# How many solutions are there for the equation?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Good night, question is this;

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 67$$
 when each odd indexed variable $(x_1,x_3,x_5)$ is a positive odd integer and each even indexed variable $(x_2,x_4)$ is a positive even integer.

In my book there is a simple example about that, and it was solved with repetition combination. How can use that for this question? Or should I use generating function for result?
Thanks for helps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Letting $x_1=2a_1+1$, $x_2=2a_2+2$, $x_3=2a_3+1$, $x_4=2a_4+2$ and $x_5=2a_5+1$ the equation becomes
$$
a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5=30
$$
and we are looking for non-negative integer solutions.

Answer. $\binom{34}{4}$ - In general, $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$.

Comment: Is answer only $\binom{34}{4}$ or should we use also another operation like stars and bars after that

Comment: oh no, this is just a stars and bars, and then we have $\binom{30+5-1}{4}$, right?

Comment: Exactly $\binom{34}{4}$ is the answer. No more.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x_{i}=2y_{i}+1$ for $i\in\left\{ 1,3,5\right\} $ and $x_{i}=2y_{i}+2$
for $i\in\left\{ 2,4\right\} $.

Then to be solved is actually: $$y_{1}+y_{2}+y_{3}+y_{4}+y_{5}=30$$
where the $y_{i}$ are nonnegative integers.

We find $\binom{30+4}{4}$ solutions by application of [stars
and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).